# Eclipse overwrite test resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In my Java Maven application I have source folders:

> src/main/java
>  src/main/resources
>
> src/test/java
>  src/test/resources
>
> src/integrationTest/java
>  src/integrationTest/resources

In every resource folder I have program.properties file, but if I run test by right click -> run as -> JUnit test, it loads wrong properties file (integration tests are running with unit tests properties).

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to load resources from X/resources when running tests from X/java ?

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using? Also, it would help if you update your question with your .classpath

Comment: Once you run the unit test as mentioned there will be a new run configuration in that corresponds to that test(Run->Run Configurations). Try adding your resource folder in the Classpath tab.